# ListView в NestedScrollView в высоту как один айтем

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-layout

Имеется список, при открытии фрагмента разметка отображается не правильно, отображается только 1 элемент из списка, чтоб увидеть следующий нужно скролить, в чем может быть проблема (*если убрать NestedScrollView, то все отображается правильно, но я его не могу убрать он нужен, как это исправить по другому*)?

**main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:bb_behavior="shifting|shy"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs_color_changing" />
```

**setting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is more fragment"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textSize="36sp"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**смена фрагмента**

```
MoreFragment f = new MoreFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
```

Comment: у FrameLayout может быть надо выставить значение высоты в `match_parent`

Comment: @andreich, пробовал не помогает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением атрибута `android:fillViewport="true"`, ответ нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881222/listview-not-expanding-inside-nestedscrollview)